# Authorization code AND Authorize attribute in WebAPI Controllers

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, web-applications, asp.net-web-api

I have the following method to retrieve a folder:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Authorize]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetFolder(int id)
    {
        FolderDto folder = _service.GetFolder(id);
        if (folder == null)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Found, folder);
    }
```

I have authorization working - if the user is logged in and passes a request with a valid cookie, the action proceeds.  But I only want to allow the user to get Folders that are his - that is, those folders with a UserId of his User ID in the membership tables.

Should I perform this check in the controller for every one of my WebAPI controller methods, or if there's a standard approach here that I haven't learned about yet.  My gut tells me to do this:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Authorize]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetFolder(int id)
    {
        FolderDto folder = _service.GetFolder(id);
        if (folder == null || folder.UserId != <userId>) // Or just add another check for HTTPUnauthorized
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Found, folder);
    }
```

Thoughts?

Comment: You're showing the users folders they don't have access to or this is a edge case where you just want to make sure they don't have access?

Comment: I want to make sure users can't access folders that aren't theirs... I wouldn't call it an edge case though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to perform this authorisation during the execution of only one of the actions then I would simply put that code into that actions code. But if you have more than one actions then I would probably create an authorisation filter by extending `AuthorizeAttribute` and moving the code for folder authorisation in that filter.